# Trying to send a POST request using php, No matter what i do i get "HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: php, http, web, post

To make an HTTP request, someone suggested I try using PHP and gave me a piece of code to work on:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/dashboard/api';
$data = array('to' => PHONE_NUMBER, 'from' => SENDER_ID, 'message' => TEXT, 'email' => EMAIL, 'api_secret' => SECRET, 'unicode' => BOOLEAN, 'id' => IDENTIFIER);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
```

So I took the code, edited the fields that I needed to, pasted it into a `.php` file, uploaded on my web server (running PHP 5.6) and then while trying to run the `.php` file, I get HTTP ERROR 500.

I'm a complete newbie to all this and I'm not even sure if I am doing everything correctly.

Comment: Check your PHP error log for the reason for 500 error.

Comment: You should learn to use `curl`, it's easier to use and more flexible.

Comment: RFC2606 compliance, formatting, removing noise

Answer (score 0):

```
      $url = 'https://domainname.com/dashboard/api';
      $params = array('to' => PHONE_NUMBER, 'from' => SENDER_ID, 'message' => TEXT, 'email' => EMAIL, 'api_secret' => SECRET, 'unicode' => BOOLEAN, 'id' => IDENTIFIER);      
      $query_content = http_build_query($params);
      $context = stream_context_create([
          'http' => [
              'header'  => [
                   'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                   'Content-Length: ' . strlen($query_content)
              ],
          'method'  => 'POST',
          'content' => $query_content
        ]
      ]);
      $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: It's giving me "PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant PHONE_NUMBER - assumed 'PHONE_NUMBER'" for each one and in the end PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://domainname.com/dashboard/api): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error :(((

Comment: Have you checked the URL you are trying to access is working properly? To test this, you could try $_POST = $_GET; at the start of the file, and try with URL parameters

Comment: Also, are you replacing PHONE NUMBER with an actual phone number? i.e. "01234567890" in quotation marks, so it is a string? Similarly with the other variables?

Comment: or have you defined php variables as PHONE_NUMBER ? Seems like an odd way to so it, but I'm not sure how you set those variables up

Comment: @hopwJan In the question you said you edited the fields you needed to edit. That should mean that you defined all the constants that you're sending as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://domainname.com/dashboard/api';
$header = [
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
];
$params = array('to' => PHONE_NUMBER, 'from' => SENDER_ID, 'message' => TEXT, 'email' => EMAIL, 'api_secret' => SECRET, 'unicode' => BOOLEAN, 'id' => IDENTIFIER);
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$res = curl_exec($c);
var_dump($res);
```